# Get N maximum values and indices along an axis in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I think this is an easy question for experienced numpy users.

I have a score matrix. The raw index corresponds to samples and column index corresponds to items. For example,

```
score_matrix = 
  [[ 1. ,  0.3,  0.4],
   [ 0.2,  0.6,  0.8],
   [ 0.1,  0.3,  0.5]]
```

I want to get top-M indices of items for each samples. Also I want to get top-M scores. For example,

```
top2_ind = 
  [[0, 2],
   [2, 1],
   [2, 1]]

top2_score = 
  [[1. , 0.4],
   [0,8, 0.6],
   [0.5, 0.3]]
```

What is the best way to do this using numpy?

Comment: @Kasramvd The linked dup target answer for 2D doesn't keep the order from highest to lowest as needed for this question. So, I am reopening, hope that sounds okay.

Comment: @Divakar My answer has provided an ordered result.

Comment: @Kasramvd Well [`np.argpartition docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) state that to keep the order, we need to provide it a sequence of ints, which I think would be range of those indices, i.e. `range(N)` inside `np.argpartition()`. Were you using any such thing there? Sorry if I missed that!

Comment: @Divakar No, but certainly still it doesn't justify that this is not a duplicate. Also I don't think that this approach makes any significant difference with `argsort` version.

Comment: @Kasramvd That would depend a lot on the sizes. But here's a [`runtime test`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37036444/3293881) , where `N` is significantly smaller than the axis length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `argsort()`:

```
top2_ind = score_matrix.argsort()[:,::-1][:,:2]
```

That is, produce an array which contains the indices which would sort `score_matrix`:

```
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Then reverse the columns with `::-1`, then take the first two columns with `:2`:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 1]])
```

Then similar but with regular `np.sort()` to get the values:

```
top2_score = np.sort(score_matrix)[:,::-1][:,:2]
```

Which following the same mechanics as above, gives you:

```
array([[ 1. ,  0.4],
       [ 0.8,  0.6],
       [ 0.5,  0.3]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) -

```
idx = np.argpartition(a,range(M))[:,:-M-1:-1] # topM_ind
out = a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],idx]    # topM_score
```

Sample run -

```
In [343]: a
Out[343]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.3,  0.4],
       [ 0.2,  0.6,  0.8],
       [ 0.1,  0.3,  0.5]])

In [344]: M = 2

In [345]: idx = np.argpartition(a,range(M))[:,:-M-1:-1]

In [346]: idx
Out[346]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 1]])

In [347]: a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],idx]
Out[347]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.4],
       [ 0.8,  0.6],
       [ 0.5,  0.3]])
```

Alternatively, possibly slower, but a bit shorter code to get `idx` would be with `np.argsort` -

```
idx = a.argsort(1)[:,:-M-1:-1]
```

Here's a [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37036444/3293881) containing some runtime test that compares `np.argsort` and `np.argpartition` on a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in the both the values and corresponding indices without tempering with the order, the following simple approach will be helpful. Though it could be computationally expensive if working with large data since we are using a *list* to store *tuples* of value, index.

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([0.01,0.6, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1,0.7, 0.12]) # a simple array
values_indices = [] # define an empty list to store values and indices
while values.shape[0]>1:
    values_indices.append((values.max(), values.argmax()))
    # remove the maximum value from the array:
    values = np.delete(values, values.argmax())
```

The final output as list of tuples:

```
values_indices
[(0.7, 5), (0.6, 1), (0.4, 1), (0.12, 3), (0.1, 2), (0.01, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be:

To get top-2 **indices**

```
np.argsort(-score_matrix)[:, :2]
```

To get top-2 **values**

```
-np.sort(-score_matrix)[:, :2]
```